# Motion Service Hanging Up Pi?

Tags: raspicam, motion

I have had a raspberry pi B+ for a little over a year now, and I've noticed consistent performance issues after running motion service for a long period (anything over an hour or so). Originally I was using an older USB camera from a thrift store, then a newer usb camera, and now a picam and it's the same response. I have a hard time ssh'ing or vnc'ing into my pi. Each time, I just delete all of the files created from the motion service in /var/lib/motion and then it works fine.

Has anyone else seen issues with this? Is there another tool/service I can use to record video and stream it over ip?

Comment: @Fabian I believe the directory /var/lib/motion is onboard

Comment: @Fabian SanDisk Ultra PLUS 64GB microSD Card, Imaging, Class 10. 80 MB/s

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80255/time-lapse-images-not-fully-rendered-with-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your SD card](https://www.sandisk.com/home/memory-cards/sd-cards/ultra-plus-sd) is too slow with 5MB/s **write speed** for this use case. I recommend to get a [Class 3 (U3) SD card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_Card#Speeds) (or better). Or you could store the files on an external drive (HDD/SSD with USB or NAS).

Comment: I will try this out.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I actually had my sd cards mixed up, and really had an 8GB sandisk Class 1 4MB/s. I ended up upgrading, after some reading about classes, to a 64GB Extreme PLUS sandisk Class3 30MB/s. 

After the upgrade I've had no issues and it's running pretty smooth. It took a while to test because I was having issues recovering my old setup and actually had to just start from scratch... but thanks again!